# How to calculate 12 months from a start date

Tags: development, sharepoint-addin, visual-studio

I am building an application about workers vocation and I need some help on calculating.

**Here is what I need**:

I have a column named `startdate`, after 12 months I want the SharePoint or c# to know dynamical when 12 months has gone.

Example the start date of `worker1` is 01/01/2015 after 12 months or 1 year I want that `worker1` to get a `checked box = true`,

And `worker2` start date is 05/03/2015 after one year or 12 months same thing to 
`checked = true`

How to do it on SharePoint via formulas or in C#?

Comment: If I rephrase your question to "Make SP do something after 12 months" you don't need a calculated column, but a Workflow or some code behind which checks the date and sets the Checkbox.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess this should work for you,

Create a calculated column with such formula

```
    =DATE(YEAR([Created])+1,MONTH([Created]),DAY([Created]))
```

Do not add months to this, else you will get a wrong result in some case.

Once you have this column with values, you can create a timer job/workflow to run every day.With minimum logic, just need to check if that column value (Calculated column) is equal to todays date, and you are good to update the Yes/No field value to yes. ie in your case `"checked = true"`

Above solution will be mimimal in terms of implementation. You can remove the calculated column logic if you want, and do calculation in your workflow/timer job

Comment: Altough I also stick to your solution because it is much clearer, could you Point out a case where adding months would produce a wrong result?

Comment: Hi Leopold, Consider Created date as 01-Dec- 2015, if u add 12 month into the formula. it would appear as 
=DATE(YEAR([Created]), MONTH([Created]) + 12 , DAY([Created]))
=DATE(2015, 12 + 12, 01 ) = DATE(2015 , 24, 01)

OR

 Consider Created date as 01-Dec- 2015, if u want to add 2 month into the formula. it would appear as 
=DATE(YEAR([Created]), MONTH([Created]) + 2 , DAY([Created]))
=DATE(2015, 12 + 2, 01 ) = DATE(2015 , 14, 01)
if in both cases even if it convert it to appropriate month, the year remains same, which ideally should be next year.

Comment: @NderonHyseni Glad my solution helped you

Comment: Hi Gaurav, example given in comments for month addition is incorrect, The formula is given at MSDN site. And I just created calculated column with your example and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Create a calculated column with below formula:

```
=DATE(YEAR([Start Date]),MONTH([Start Date])+12,DAY([Start Date]))
```

This will add 12 months to your start date.
Ref: [Calculated Field formulas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb862071(v=office.14).aspx#sectionSection2)

Now to make check-box true, either you have to use designer workflow or timer job/console application.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int MonthDifference(this DateTime lValue, DateTime rValue)
{
    return (lValue.Month - rValue.Month) + 12 * (lValue.Year - rValue.Year);
}
```

Note that this returns a relative difference, meaning that if rValue is greater than lValue, then the return value will be negative. If you want an absolute difference, you can use this:

```
public static int MonthDifference(this DateTime lValue, DateTime rValue)
{
    return Math.Abs((lValue.Month - rValue.Month) + 12 * (lValue.Year - rValue.Year));
}
```

taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1526004/1294606). Now using it like following.

```
var monthDifference = MonthDifference(DateTime.Now, startdate);

if(monthDifference >= 12){

//implement your logic here

}
```

If you wish to make it by calculated column then use [`DATEDIF(start_date,end_date,unit)`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DATEDIF-function-bd549d1c-f829-4691-a77d-4a1e3d42bc1a?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US).

Answer (score 1):

**Note:**

in June 2017, Microsoft disabled the use of JavaScript in a Calculated Column

That means given answers may not apply  for newer SharePoint versions

For long explanation and work arounds see:
[June 13th 2017 Microsoft blocked handling HTML markup in SharePoint calculated fields - how to get the same functionality back](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/218102/june-13th-2017-microsoft-blocked-handling-html-markup-in-sharepoint-calculated-f/218110#218110)

---

**Original answer:**

You can **check for expired/today dates without a Workflow or Timerjob** if you:

- Do the calculation in JavaScript (*remember JS months start at 0 for january*)
- Have a **View** that is **displayed daily** (by a user with update permissions)

Add a Calculated Column (*set to datatype=Number to execute the HTML/JS*)

```
=IF(CheckedBox,"","<img src=/_layouts/images/blank.gif onload=""{"
&"var SPday=new Date("   
&YEAR([Created])    
&","    
&MONTH([Created])-1    
&","    
&DAY([Created])    
&");"
&"if(new Date() > new Date( SPday.getFullYear(), SPday.getMonth()+12 ) ){"
&    "var TR=this;while(TR.tagName!='TR'){TR=TR.parentNode}"
&    "var ID=TR.id.split(',')[1];"
&    "var ctx=SP.ClientContext.get_current();" 
&    "var list=SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList();" 
&    "var item=ctx.get_web().get_lists().getById(list).getItemById(ID);" 
&    "ctx.load(item);" 
&    "item.set_item( 'CheckedBox' ,'TRUE' );" 
&    "item.update();" 
&    "ctx.executeQueryAsync();"
&"}"
&"}"">")
```

- This code is only generated for CheckedBox==False/No values
- If the code is added (to every ListItem in the View)
- it compares the dates

  - if the date is past today
  - it updates the current listitem using JSOM (so the Modified By data is the current user)

All Pros and Cons of mixing Calculated Columns with Javascript at http://www.viewmaster365.com/#/How

ICC 010